# How to debug print the values of tmux settings?

Tags: debugging, tmux

For example, if I want to know the value of `textwidth` in vim, I can dereference it by appending a `?`. Thus, I will simply type `:set textwidth?`.

How can you do the equivalent in `tmux`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To dereference the value of a tmux setting or variable, you can run the following terminal command:

```
tmux display-pane -p #{<setting-or-variable-name>}
```

Or, to be more verbose

```
tmux display-pane -p "The value of your setting or variable is #{<setting-or-variable-name>}"
```

Example of a working command:

```
tmux display-message -p "You have #{display-panes-time}ms to press a number key after running 'display-pane'"
```

---

Note: The corresponding command-prompt commands, surprisingly, will fail:

```
:display-pane #{display-panes-time}
:display-pane #{display-panes-colour}
```

However, when you add quotes, they act as expected:

```
:display-pane "#{display-panes-time}"
:display-pane "#{display-panes-colour}"
```

What...?

Comment: Version 3 of the tmux man page has a new section *PARSING SYNTAX* which explains that unquoted `#` in a command in the conf file or at the command prompt `:` starts a comment, hence the need for quotes.

Comment: You can also use `show-options`, for example `show -g display-panes-time`, to show a single option.